Draw a nomogram for a logistic regression (full data not available, only intercept and coefficients)
I would like to draw a nomogram for a logistic regression. Unfortunately, I do not have the full dataset, but I have the intercept and the coefficients.
I found an example in python (https://spj.science.org/doi/10.34133/hds.0023 that also provides an app to generate nomograms (https://visdata.bjmu.edu.cn/nomogram; click english on the top right), but I am looking for a solution in R.
I learned that the rms package allows drawing a nice nomogram (https://rpubs.com/clayford/nomogram); however, for that, I would need an lrm object.
Could I somehow generate a "blank" lrm object and adjust it and then draw a nomogram using rms::nomogram()?
Or is there an easier way to get a nomogram with the values I have? Maybe a ggplot based option?
Example data:
# Define the coefficients
coef_intercept <- -12.364
coef_X <- 0.826
coef_Y <- 0.426
coef_Z <- 5.111

X and Y are linear (range 0-20), Z is a binary variable.

Calculating the data behind a nomogram is not that difficult.  The difficult (and tedious) bit is turning the data into pleasing and accurate visuals.  As a frame challenge, in these days of easy-to-write apps and web pages, perhaps a Shiny app or similar would be more useful?

The examples in the help page of nomogram show you how to simulate data from a given set of coefficients.

@Edward Thank you, do you mean rms::nomogram ?

@Limey Thank you, that's a good idea. The authors of the Python solution created an app (https://visdata.bjmu.edu.cn/nomogram). However, I prefer the traditional display of probabilities over their implementation. Also, I'm interested in understanding how to achieve this in R. Could simulating data from a specified set of coefficients, creating an lrm object, and using rms::nomogram be a potential (quick) solution?

I don't think simulation is a sensible option here.  It will lead to inaccurate answers.  There's no need, especially when the algebra you need is straight-forward.  I already have a desciption of what you need.  Drawing the nomogram is, as I mentioned, the time-consuming part.  It might be possible to create (the parts of) the lrm object you need fairly simply, but I don't have the rms package myself.  A simple Shiny app would be about ten minutes work.

I had a look at hacking a lrm object to use the existimg nomogram() and plot.nomogram() functions from rms, but I got nowhere: the code is long and makes too many (perfectly reasonable) assumptions about the completeness of the input.
So here is a really hacky solution that gets you somewhere close to what you want.  It does produce a nomogram, but it doesn't look particularly close to the example you've provided or others that I have seen.
I rely on the tidyverse, so start with:
library(tidyverse)

The heart of the solution is the parameterScale function. It takes the parameter estimate and a variable's range of possible values and does "something useful": it creates a tibble that describes that variables contribution to the nomogram.
#' @param title (`character`) The character string used to label thhis part of the nomogram
#' @param order (`numeric`) The position of this variable on the nomogram's y axis
#' @param xmin (`numeric`) The minimum possible value for this variable
#' @param xmin (`numeric`) The maximum possible value for this variable
#' @param zmin (`numeric`) The value on the nomogram's x axis to which 
#' `xmin` should be transformed
#' @param zmax (`numeric`) The value on the nomogram's x axis to which 
#' `xmax` should be transformed
#' @param steps (`numeric`) The number of steps that should appear on 
#' this variable's entry on the nomogram
#' @param xfmt (`character`) The format used to display this variable's 
#' x values on the nomogram
#' @param zfmt (`character`) The format used to display this variable's 
#' logit scores on the nomogram
#' @param post_hook (`function`)  The function that does anything variable-specific 
#' after standard manipulation is complete.  The default value does nothing
parameterScale <- function(
  title, 
  order, 
  xmin = 0, 
  xmax = 1, 
  zmin = 0, 
  zmax = 1, 
  steps, 
  xfmt, 
  zfmt, 
  mult = 1, 
  post_hook = function(x) x
) {
  xx <- tibble(
    Title = title,
    Order = order,
    X = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = steps),
    Z = seq(zmin, zmax, length.out = steps),
    XLabel = str_trim(sprintf(xfmt, X)),
    ZLabel = NA_character_
  )
  if (!is.na(zfmt)) {
    xx <- xx %>% mutate(ZLabel = sprintf(zfmt, X * mult))
  }
  xx %>% post_hook()
}

So, for example,
z <- parameterScale(
  title = "Z",
  zmax = 0.2,
  steps = 2,
  order = 3,
  xfmt = "%1.0f",
  zfmt = "%5.3f",
  mult = 5.111
)
z
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  Title Order     X     Z XLabel ZLabel
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1 Z         3     0   0   0      0.000 
2 Z         3     1   0.2 1      5.111 

Now, define a few constants
# For plotting
yOffset <- 0.1
# Minimum possible value of the linear predictor (not used in solution)
wMin <- -12.364 
# Maximum possible value of the linear predictor (not used in solution)
wMax <- -12.364 + 0.826 * 20 + 0.426 *20 + 5.111

Now create the other elements that are needed for the nomogram, and bind them together.
x <- parameterScale(
  title = "X",
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 20,
  zmin = 0,
  zmax = 1,
  steps = 5,
  order = 1,
  mult = 0.826,
  xfmt = "%2.0f",
  zfmt = "%5.3f"
)

z <- parameterScale(
  title = "Z",
  zmax = 0.2,
  steps = 2,
  order = 3,
  xfmt = "%1.0f",
  zfmt = "%5.3f",
  mult = 5.111
)

y <- parameterScale(
  title = "Y",
  xmax = 20,
  steps = 5,
  order = 2,
  mult = 0.426,
  xfmt = "%1.0f",
  zfmt = "%5.3f"
)

total <- parameterScale(
  title = "Total points",
  xmax = 35,
  zmax =  exp(wMax) / (1 + exp(wMax)),
  order = 4,
  steps = 8,
  xfmt = "%2.0f",
  zfmt = NA,
  post_hook = function(x) {
    x %>% mutate(
      ZLabel = sprintf("%5.3f", (exp(-12.364 + X)/(1 + exp(-12.364 + X)))),
      ZLabel = ifelse(ZLabel == "1.000", ">0.999", ZLabel),
      ZLabel = ifelse(ZLabel == "0.000", "<0.001", ZLabel),
    )
  }
)

d <- bind_rows(x, y, z, total)

Finally, produce the nomogram.
d %>% 
  group_by(Order) %>% 
  mutate(
    ZUpper = max(Z), 
    ZLower = min(Z)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(
      xmin = ZLower, 
      xmax = ZUpper, 
      y = Order
    )
  ) +
  geom_text(
    nudge_y = -2.5 * yOffset, 
    vjust = "bottom", 
    hjust = "middle", 
    aes(x = Z, y = Order, label = XLabel)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    nudge_y = 2.5 * yOffset, 
    vjust = "top", 
    hjust = "middle", 
    colour = "blue", 
    aes(x = Z, y = Order, label = ZLabel)
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = Z, y = Order, yend = Order - yOffset)
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = d %>% filter(!is.na(ZLabel)), 
    aes(x = Z, y = Order, yend = Order + yOffset)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = unique(d$Order), 
    labels = unique(d$Title)
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank()
  )

which gives

To check the nomogram gives credible answers, consider an individual with covariates x = 5, y = 15 and z = 1.  Their event risk is
w <- -12.364 + 5.111*1 + 0.426*15 + 0.826*5
exp(w)/(1 + exp(w))
[1] 0.9632792

The nomogram gives this individual a total points score of 5.111 + 6.390 + 4.130 = 15.631.  Looking at the "Total score" line, a score of 15 translates to an event risk of 0.933, which is comsistent with the exact answer of 0.963 for a risk score of 15.631.
You can format the nomogram to get closer to your exact target, but this should give you (almost) everything you need for further manipulation.

Thank you so much for your great efforts! I really appreciate it. Since Edward's answer is a bit closer to what I was looking for, I'll be accepting his answer. However, I think your approach could be very useful for others. Thanks again!

Of course, you are welcome to choose whichever answer you like.  However, bear in mind that mine is exact.  Anything based on simulation will only ever be an approximation.

You could simulate the data using the known coefficients and then run the lrm function on this data.
library(rms)

# Define the coefficients
coef_intercept <- -12.364
coef_X <- 0.826
coef_Y <- 0.426
coef_Z <- 5.111

#Sample size
n <- 1000    # define sample size

set.seed(17) # so can reproduce the results

d <- data.frame(X=runif(n, 0,20),
                Y=runif(n, 0,20),
                Z=sample(c(0,1), size=n, replace=TRUE))

# Specify population model for log odds that Y=1
# Simulate binary y to have Prob(y=1) = 1/[1+exp(-L)]
d <- upData(d,
            L = coef_intercept+coef_X*X + coef_Y*Y + coef_Z*(Z==1),
            y = ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0))

ddist <- datadist(d); options(datadist='ddist')

# Run the model
f <- lrm(y ~ X+Y+Z, data=d)

# Create the nomogram and plot it
nom <- nomogram(f, fun=plogis, fun.at=c(.001,.01,.1,.5,.9,.99,.999))
plot(nom)


For X, Y, and Z values of 5, 10, and 1 the predicted probability of the outcome is 0.73:
Predict(f, X=5, Y=10, Z=1, fun=plogis)
  X  Y Z      yhat     lower     upper
1 5 10 1 0.7342753 0.6460705 0.8070626

And this is close to the value you get from using the nomogram (25+25+30=80). I added the vertical dashed line to the plot to help you see.

Not a nomogram, I realise, but in case it is useful, here's a basic shiny app that calculates event probabilities based on user inputs.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Nomogram"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x", "X", min = 0, max = 20, value = 0, step  = 0.1),
      sliderInput("y", "Y", min = 0, max = 20, value = 0, step = 0.1),
      sliderInput("z", "Z", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("prob")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$prob <- renderPrint({
      z <- -12.364 + 0.826 * input$x + 0.426 * input$y + 5.111 * input$z
      p <- exp(z) / ( 1 + exp(z))
      cat(
        paste0(
          "Input values of x = ", input$x,
          ", y = ", input$y,
          ", z = ", input$z,
          " give rise to a risk score of ",
          round(z, 2),
           " and an event probability of ",
          round(p, 3),
          "."
        )
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Edit
In response to OP's comment below.
You want a graph, here's a graph.  But it's not a nomogram.  The calculation in the renderPrint does the manual work that a nomogram helps a human to do, but does it automatically.

The reason that a nomogram is difficult and tedious to construct is that it needs to convert covariate values to risk scores on the log-odds scale and then convert the risk scores back into probability.  That means the positions and lengths of the various covariate scales are critical.  They may look arbitrary, but they are not.  Nomograms are, IMHO, an out-of-date construct that is no longer necessary.

So here's an alternative.  It shows a heat map of probabilty of event for combinations of x, y and z.  For your particular application, it's not very interesting because - for each value of z - risk is dominated by the value of x and the gradient of the curve around the point of inflection is very steep.
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Nomogram"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x", "X", min = 0, max = 20, value = 0, step  = 0.1),
      sliderInput("y", "Y", min = 0, max = 20, value = 0, step = 0.1),
      sliderInput("z", "Z", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("prob"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$prob <- renderPrint({
      z <- -12.364 + 0.826 * input$x + 0.426 * input$y + 5.111 * input$z
      p <- exp(z) / ( 1 + exp(z))
      cat(
        paste0(
          "Input values of x = ", input$x,
          ", y = ", input$y,
          ", z = ", input$z,
          " give rise to a risk score of ",
          round(z, 2),
           " and an event probability of ",
          round(p, 3),
          "."
        )
      )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    tibble() %>% 
      expand(
        X = seq(0, 20, 0.1),
        Y = seq(0, 20, 0.1),
        Z = c(0, 1)
      ) %>% 
      mutate(
        W = exp(-12.364 + 0.826 * X + 0.426 * Y + 5.11 * Z),
        P = W / (1 + W)
      ) %>% 
      ggplot() +
      geom_tile(aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = P)) +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
      facet_wrap(vars(Z), labeller = label_both) + 
      theme_light()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The plot looks like this:

The plot is not reactive because it effectively represents the risk for all combinations of x, y and z, not just the specific one defined by the widgets in the sidebar.

That is awesome, thank you! I see that this is more useful and accurate than a classical nomogram in many ways. However, I still want to create a nomogram for a non-digital setting where the model's probability can be visually estimated in a simple graph.

Ah!  And there's the rub: a nomogram is not simple...

Sorry if I misunderstood your earlier comment. I thought a Shiny solution would include a graphical representation. I ended up here because creating a nomogram is quite challenging.

No apology necessary.  You didn't misunderstand.  I'm simply suggesting that, I believe these days, there are better options than a nomogram, especially if you can't crate the nomogram at the click of a mouse.

Thank you for the edit. The graph is marvelous! I really like it, even though I cannot fully read it (unfortunately I belong to the 0.5%...). I totally agree that there are much better options than nomograms (I made an easy calculator myself a while ago). I work in the medical field and unfortunately, things change very, very slowly here. Many medical journals may not accept online calculators and still request old-school nomograms. Might a bounty be appropriate since it sounds like a lot of work?

"unfortunately I belong to the 0.5%...":  Oh.  My apologies.  Sometimes, attempting to focus on the fundamentals allows an important side issue to slip down a crack.  You will probably be interested in this.  (In fact, I normally use brewer scales by default.  I didn't here because I didn't want to distract from what I thought were the sessentials...

...In this case, try replacing geom_tile(aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = P)) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") with geom_tile(aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = cut(P, breaks = seq(0.1, 1.0, 0.1)))) + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div").  Of course, you can experiment to get an even better result.  A bounty might help, but a good solution will be a considerable effort.  It might be worth exploring options based around constructing a psedo-lrm solution.
